# How to retrieve value from pdo array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I am trying to get the value for total from this array to put into a variable:

```
Array ( 

[0] => Array ( [Variable_name] => var1 [Value] => 2 ) 
[1] => Array ( [Variable_name] => total [Value] => 1 ) 
[2] => Array ( [Variable_name] => var3 [Value] => 0.002 ) 

)
```

PHP:

```
$data = $array->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $data[1]['total'];

foreach ($data as $result){
     echo $result['total'];
}

foreach ($data as $result){
     echo $result[1]['total'];
}
```

None of the above echo the variable, if I use `print_r($array->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));` it prints the array, what is the correct way to do this?

In short: I want to get the value from the key `Value`, where the `Variable_name` is holding the value `total`. Here in this example it would be 1.

Comment: You know that total is a value and not a key in the array?! Do you want the key for the total value? Or what do you exactly want?

Comment: @Rizier123:  I got to use what I love more, only minutes after :-)

Comment: I want to store the value from total in a variable, $myvariable = 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to get the variable names as indexes in an array:

```
$vars = array_column($data, null, 'Variable_name');

echo $vars['total']['Value'];  // displays 1
echo $vars['var3']['Value'];   // displays 0.002
```

Or if you only need the value for each one:

```
$vars = array_column($data, 'Value', 'Variable_name');

echo $vars['total'];  // displays 1
echo $vars['var3'];   // displays 0.002
```